# How do I view my usage for Firestore over the last 30 days?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, billing, quota

I'm trying to check out what my overall usage was for the previous billing cycle. When I go to my project's usage the best I can get is this URL:

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/PROJ/database/firestore/usage/last-7d/reads

The last 7 days is not enough for any monthly billing cycle, and it seems impossible to find a 30 day breakdown. Any idea where to look?

Also, "detailed usage" shows even less, it shows only the time since midnight last night!

Comment: Couldn't find it either on my own projects... I guess you'll have to open a request to Google :). I mean, they have all the metrics, all they have to do is add an extra option like *Last 30 days*

Comment: Super weird! thanks for checking!